# Why `read -N` doesn't work in this script on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

could anyone please advise me how to fix this for a terminal in macos?
Thank you for your help.

```
 read -s -N1 -p "Press a key: "
 K1="$REPLY"
 read -s -N2 -t 0.001
 K2="$REPLY"
 read -s -N1 -t 0.001
 K3="$REPLY"
 key="$K1$K2$K3"
```

Error:  **read: -N: invalid option**

Full script [enter link description here](https://abs.traduc.org/abs-6.4/BashExtraKeys.sh.txt)

Comment: Incidentally, the usual idiom is to name the variable as the argument to `read`, rather than collect everything in `REPLY` and then reassign it; like `read -s -N1 -p "Press a key: " K1`

Comment: Be careful with the ABS; you should probably find a less error-prone and opinionated guide for learning Bash.

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/bash` is version 3.2.57 (or similar) which doesn't support `-N`. You can use `-n` instead (with slightly different functionality so not sure the timeouts used for K2 and K3 still work).

If you need Bash 5 you can install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i get an error : read: 0.001: invalid timeout specification. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: @host Get Bash 5 :-)

Comment: I installed GNU bash, verze 5.1.12(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0). Same error :(

Comment: @Host You need to change the first line of your script as well, to point to the newly installed version 5.